# wanted to filter all the records created in last 24 hours with Django filter but timestamp stored epoch format in CharField

Tags: django, orm

**problem context** - I've a django model like this.

```
class UpdateRequests(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    field_new_value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_at = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    request_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=JOS_STATUS)
    request_close_date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**problem statement -** I want to fetch all records created with in last 24 hours.

**how I was trying -** I was trying like this in my view function

```
time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

results = UpdateRequests.objects.filter(created_at__lte=time_threshold,
                                            request_status="Pending").values()
```

**but it is not working and I guess because django __lte , __gte works on DateTimeField() only.**
reference - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/

Please help me with this, I don't want to change the schema since it's already in the production.

Comment: You can use __lte and __gte with Chatfield as well. It will return results based on lexicographical order. Filter with an epoch time string..

epoch_str = str(int(int(time_threshold.timestamp())))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bruh you stored datetime in charfield `created_at = models.CharField(max_length=10)` How can db serve you Datetime Object? you have to make changes in Models and create objects again with this

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True,auto_now_add=True)
```

`auto_now_add=True` Will fetch current datetime when you will Create Model object.

Comment: But he doesn't want to change the schema! and here you are suggesting schema change.

Comment: @RohitPrakashSingh that's the model field type change. there is no way you can filter DateTime directly with charfield. fetch ALL THE RECORDS then convert them into DATETIME Obj and then filter with whatever Date range is required.do u think its a good idea?

Comment: @Divakar Yadav you can make script to maintain old data after the changes. convert those char datetime into datetime obj and store into database